# Override phtml template file

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

Simple issue :

This is one of magento template core file : `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml`

How can I overide it ?

I tried to create this one but it failed

`app/code/Cpy/Sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml`

I guess I can't just use a preference like I'm doing with class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template file path is associated to the block in layout xml files. So even if you create a new template file(.phtml), you need to override the appropriate layout xml and provide the path of new template file to be used. In your case you have to create two files in new module.

**1. app/code/Cpy/Sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml** - updated phtml

**2. app/code/Cpy/Sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Cpy_Sales::order/totals.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope it was helpful.

Thanks